# How to retrieve multiple columns from non-entity type sql query?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a view in database with several columns. I am trying this query

```
public class TestEntity
{
    public string ref { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Batch { get; set; }
}
var res = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TestEntity>("Select * from dbo.MyView").ToList();
```

but this returns list of objects with only null values and no data.
However, when I try to retrieve single column like this it works

```
var res = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select Name from dbo.MyView").ToList();
```

I have noticed that the problem is with the TestEntity because when I use string instead of TestEntity it works.
Any suggestion what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Filter the `NULL` records -> `WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL AND Col2 IS NOT NULL..`

Comment: I'm sorry. I wanted to say that everything is null. All the result

Comment: are the column names in the database the same as in your class? otherwise you'll need a modelBuilder in your context or change your SQL query to "SELECT ... as ref, ... as Name [...]"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

just replace the below code

```
var res = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<TestEntity>("Select * from dbo.MyView").ToList();
```

with this and try again...

```
var res = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery("Select * from dbo.MyView").ToList<TestEntity>();
```

and if still that is not working then you need to check for your

> TestEntity

and your

> dbo.MyView

for same columns. because if there is different columns in MyView and TestEntity then it will not work...

If you change the column name in query, then it will throw an exception or it'll not work properly...

if this'll help you then don't forget to mark...

Thanks...

Comment: I do think both of these lines are equal, since object materialization is done on .ToList() anyways.

Comment: Did you try it or not?

Comment: Yes the problem was mismatched names. I had dashes ("-") in my sql view where as c# doesn't support this syntax so entities were without dashed. That was the reason. Thank you for your help.